# How can I get the CPU usage for a given process out of collectd?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, graphite, collectd

I'm running multiple ubuntu (precise) boxes & I've got collectd pushing data up to a central logstash box, which is then sending it to carbon (graphite).

I'm running the [processes plugin](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Processes) for collectd, which gives CPU time with a 10 second interval.  What I want to be able to chart in graphite is the cpu usage (either in jiffies or preferably in a percentage, but I realise that can be problematic) for each process.

I'm just not grokking how to take the process CPU time metric which is a ever-increasing counter of the cpu time used by the process and turn that into a gauge of how much cpu the process is using over time.

Can I do this, and if so, how?

Comment: could you please share the graphite query to plot the graph in grafana? Am also using the Processes plugin of collectd to monitor the cpu usage of individual process on a system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the value you're referring to is a multiple of jiffies. I remember you have to divide it by a power of 10, then you can simply convert it to a percentage by converting it to a rate (e.g. by plotting its derivative in graphite)

Comment: This is a vague answer that could benefit by providing a working example.